# timeseries with gg plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used ggplot in order to plot price vs time but I get something like this and i want something more clear..

```
ggplot(aes(x=time,y=price),data=df) + geom_point()
```

The cols price and time look like :

```
Price            Time
99               00:00
99               00:17
101              00:23
..                ..
..                ..
..                ..
103              23:56
```

[Price vs Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t8W9.png)

Could someone help me?

Comment: price =c(99,99,..........,104)
Time=c(00:00,00:13,.....,23:57)

Comment: Update your post with a snippet of your code using `dput()`.

Comment: You could set the y and x axis labels in ggplot, and try geom_line instead of geom_point (or both), but I can't give you an example if you don't share at least some of your data.

Comment: your time is being plotted as a factor(or character). Change it to a time format (e.g., hm format in the lubridate package)

Comment: `price=HB2[,3]
price=as.matrix(price)
timestamp=HB2[,7]
timestamp=as.matrix(timestamp)
df=data.frame(price,time=dmy_hm(timestamp))
time=as.POSIXct(df$time)
S=format(time,format="%H:%M")
time=as.matrix(S)
df=cbind(price,time)
df=as.data.frame(df)
df=rename(df, c("V1"="Price", "V2"="Time"))
Time=as.matrix(df$Time)
ggplot(aes(x=time,y=price),data=df) + geom_point()




This is the code i used, however I'm still stuck :s :s

Comment: put actual code in the question - along with reasonable data. AS it stands nobody is going to fully understand what you have going on.